# Which version of Eclipse can be used to manipulate TFS files

Tags: eclipse, tfs, eclipse-plugin

I need to connect to TFS to edit files, generally they are of the `.sql` and `.cs` variant some times I need `.aspx` also. I do now want to purchase Microsoft visual studio.

So kindly tell me which Eclipse I should install to fulfill my requirement.
 because there are many type of eclipse available like 
 Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, Eclipse for Parallel Application Developers etc.

Comment: [Installing the Team Foundation Server Plug-in for Eclipse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh301122.aspx) should cover the information you need. It wouldn't hurt if you tried a little research yourself.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By installing

- [Team explorer Everywhere](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/team-explorer-everywhere-vs.aspx)
- and [eGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/)

you get access to TFS from eclipse (both to TFVC and Git repositories). That doesn't add anything to edit T-SQL or C# files. But you can edit them in simple text edit mode. You can use any version of Eclipse as basis, as no version comes with the right plugins you need, but I would recommend to check the free versions of Visual Studio first.

If you want a free version that can edit files created by a paid version of Visual Studio, you can pick from the following options:

- [Visual Studio Express](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) (free license)
- [Visual Studio Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs) (free license with restrictions)
- [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/) (free, open source)
- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/) (free, open source)
- [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (free, cross platform)

Or extend Eclipse with additional plugins to handle other file formats:

- C#: http://emonic.sourceforge.net/
- look in the eclipse marketplace for other plugins for other file formats.